# Gregorian Calendar .How to find monday?

Tags: c

Can anyone of you help me with its logic.
According to Gregorian Calendar,It was Monday on the date 01 01 01.If any year is input through keyboard write a program to find out what is the day on 1st January of this year.

Comment: What have you written? What have you researched? What issues have you encountered?

Comment: Note Stack overflow questions are usually best recieved when you've tried something, encountered some problem and then posted: your attempt, what you're trying to achieve and what went wrong

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Zeller's Congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence), which will tell you the day of the week for any given date.

It looks like this:

```
int getDayOfWeek(int day, int month, int year) {

    int aa = (14 - month) / 12;
    int yy = year - aa;
    int mm = (month + (12 * aa)) - 2;

    int dayOfWeek = (day + yy + (yy / 4) - (yy / 100) + (yy / 400) + ((31 * mm) / 12)) % 7;

    return ((dayOfWeek + 6) % 7) + 1;
}
```

The function returns the date in ISO format, where Monday == 1 and Sunday == 7

Answer (score -1):

how the program works:

First We ask the user to input any year(yr)

We are asked to find the jan 1 that means we need only the previous year's last date.Assume we need to find 2010.We can find it in this day number of days from 1900 to 2009+1..Hope you understand now.We don't need the whole days of the input year.

Then We find the difference between the referenced year(1900 or byr)

Then we find the no. of leap years from the difference by dividing by 4(lp)

Then we find the how many normal years are there in between(rem)

Then we calculate total days 365*normal days +366*no. of leap years+1
We added 1 as we have to find for jan 1 and not for december 31st.

Then we find the remainder from total days and rest you can understand

I found several codes but all were confusing so I created a simple and working one.

Eg-user inputs 2010=>2009=>2009-1900=>109=>27 leap years and rest normal years.multiply 366 with no. of leap yrs and 365 with normal years and add 1 at end(to find jan 1 of 2010) Use modulus operator and you will get the no. jan 1 in week.0==monday,1==tuesday,3==wed and so on.

```
main(){
int yr,byr=1900,lp,rem,td,day;
printf("Enter year:");
scanf("%d",&yr);
yr=(yr-1)-byr;
lp=yr/4;
rem=yr-lp;
td=(rem*365)+(lp*366)+1;
day=td%7;
if (day==0)
    printf("Monday");
else if (day==1)
    printf("Tuesday");
else if (day==2)
    printf("Wednesday");
else if (day==3)
    printf("Thursday");
else if (day==4)
    printf("Friday");
else if (day==5)
    printf("Saturday");
else if (day==6)
    printf("Sunday");
}
```